# Host executables on GitHub?

Tags: github, executable

I want to distribute executables along with my source. My source is all hosted tidily on GitHub. Is it possible to add executables and installers to my GitHub project page without adding them to my git repository?

---

Note, for some reason GitHub discontinued this feature. See Answer by Justin Dearing below.

Comment: Since the accepted answer is outdated, wouldn't it be better to accept the other, accurate answer? It's just that people see the accepted answer first.

Comment: Good point @Neftas. I will adjust to the up to date answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

<del>You cannot [host executables on github](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads).</del>

You can now use [releases](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software).

Comment: As was updated in the linked page, the new Releases feature can be used to upload executables and installers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use GitHub's [Releases](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) for that.