# Hosting executable on github

Tags: github

I want allow users to download executable of one of my project on github, without downloading all sources or browsing the entire project.

According to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928362/host-executables-on-github), you could use a upload/download service, which apparently, github has [shut down](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads).

So is there another way? Is github aiming at sharing code only, not software?

Comment: Note: you now can define a release in GitHub and host executable that way: see [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14034459/6309)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create another repository to host all your builds , I mean executable files . With in that repository don't add any of your code other than your builds ,

As a result of this , people can click on download Zip button at git hub , which downloads only executable ( as a zip file ).

while building you can copy the  executable file in a folder just push to remote repository which is hosting only builds .

Hope this helps .

basically , GIT is just an SCM ( source code management system ) it is not meant for this purpose .

but still this how you can utilize the service of github.org amd git .

hope this helps .

**EDIT : -**

Git hub now has a solution for hosting releases it has been well explained by @VonC in the post below . Please use that as a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't want to mess with another repo and left the binary executable in the main repo, but maybe I should try another host provider.

Comment: @corentin you can also upload it in a dorpbox account , and share the link with your customers , I guess drop box has file version system .

Comment: DO NOT.  Pushing binaries to git is never a good idea.  Use releases, as described below.

Comment: @Kwpolska, by the time I posted this the release option was not there, Its better you see the post date and then decide.

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara I did notice, and I knew about it.  However, this answer is the accepted answer, and also bad advice — and people might not read far enough to know this is a very bad thing to do.

Comment: It'd be cool to put the edit to the top :-)

Answer (score 50):

[Update 2d July 2013](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software), you now can **define a release**.

[image: release]

- Releases are accompanied by release notes and links to download the software or source code.
- Following the conventions of many Git projects, releases are tied to Git tags. You can use an existing tag, or let releases create the tag when it's published.
- **You can also attach binary assets (such as compiled executables, minified scripts, documentation) to a release**. Once published, the release details and assets are available to anyone that can view the repository.

This is what replaces the [old binary upload service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6978954/6309), which was [removed in December 2012](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads)!

---

Ideally, you would store your executable in an *artifact* repository, as opposed as a *source* repository like GitHub.
So yes, GitHub is for source control management, not deliveries (like binaries produced from your code).

**[Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)** is the usual choice for *any* generated artifacts like binaries, with a free upload possibility for open-source projects.
See "[How do I get my software into Central?](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/20914616-how-do-i-get-my-software-into-central)" (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4922603/6309), also mentioned in "[Maven repository hosting for non-public artifacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525929/maven-repository-hosting-for-non-public-artifacts)")

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, YMMV.  On a MAC and using Chrome browser, after getting to [this page](https://github.com/dexygen/Tatu/blob/master/tatuMicro.kit) I clicked on the "Raw" button (the "View Raw" link also worked), and it downloaded the executable tatuMicro.kit to my Downloads folder

Answer (score 0):

An exe file can be hosted under releases and the link can be distributed among friends etc. I tested it as recently as yesterday. Only issue is if someone sabotages the program for profit. The exe files can be moved around and distributed easily on pendrives.