# Where to deploy my application?

Tags: github

So I got my first [github page](http://trudler.github.io/MCpal/) that contains download buttons. I want to create buttons that link to the current version of my app.

How should I approach this? You should keep the application and the source apart from each other, but I don't have an idea where I should put my file on github to make it accessible (including a version history).

Would you link to a Sourceforge-Project or something similar? Or is there a common way for that on github?

Comment: You can host an application for free on git hub pages see docs here https://pages.github.com/ OR by creating a gh-pages in your repo https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/

Answer (score 1):

You can tag the current version (which you want to be downloaded) and make a release on github. You can give link to the release for download.

Comment: Tag an executable file? I thought tagging is meant for sourcecode.

Comment: You can find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032920/hosting-executable-on-github

Comment: What if I just create a branch for deployed files? Does that brake any pattern? Although tagging definitely seems the official way to go.