# Serve public executable from private GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I'm a contractor developing an app for a client and the code and exes are stored in a private github repository. They plan to sell the app through a WordPress-based store. I assumed or thought I read somewhere that files could be hosted on GitHub and in my tests it seemed to work – except it only worked because I was logged in to GitHub, with access to the private repo.

Is there some setting or "feature" on GitHub which will allow us to link to an exe (or zip) from another site or from a link in a "purchase confirmation" type email?

I've seen [Hosting executable on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032920/hosting-executable-on-github) but it is quite old now and not really about private repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub does allow you to host release assets as part of a release based on a tag, but these assets are controlled with the permissions of the repository.  If the repository is public, then the release assets will also be public; if it is private, then they will also be private, with the same permissions of the repository.

If what you're trying to do is use GitHub with a custom access control system to allow only people who have purchased the software to download it, then that's not possible, and you'll need to set up your own server with the binaries.  GitHub provides release assets so that folks can distribute binaries and other compiled stuff without needing to check them in, but it's not designed to be your CDN or web store.

Comment: Ok thanks. I must have misunderstood whatever I'd read – or it was referring to a public repo